# mysqli $row sum without putting it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

A small little quick question.
I want to put a sum of 2 rows in my Mysqli query. Such a sum as this:

```
echo $row['price'] / $row1['Bank'];
```

But putting it in the query itself:

```
mysqli_query($db_handle, "UPDATE playerdata SET Bank=Bank - '".$row['price'] / $row1['Bank']."' WHERE Unique_ID = '$var2'");
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. Just gives me a blank page.

Comment: please, copy/past the error it displays to you (actually you have at least one syntaxic error highlighted by Rufinus)

Comment: Just no error. sorry.

Comment: that's not a sum, it's a quotient.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysqli_query($db_handle, "UPDATE playerdata SET Bank=Bank - ".($row['price'] / $row1['Bank'])." WHERE Unique_ID = '".$var2."'");
```

to do math in strings you have to use encapsel the strings in `()`. do let mysql do the math, you dont can mix integer with strnigs. so the query has to look like this for mysql:

`UPDATE playerdata SET Bank=Bank - 20 WHERE Unique_ID = '123'`

to proof, copy the resulting sql string directly to mysql:

```
<?php
$row['price'] = 100;
$row1['Bank'] = 5;
$var2=123;

$string = "UPDATE playerdata SET Bank=Bank-".($row['price'] / $row1['Bank'])." WHERE Unique_ID = '".$var2."'";

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($db_handle, "UPDATE playerdata SET Bank='".row1['Bank'] - ($row['price'] / $row1['Bank'])."' WHERE Unique_ID = '".$var2."'");
```

make sure you really do have two sources of data, i mean for row[] and row1[];